# Symfony 4 cookies, SameSite and firefox/chrome alert

Tags: symfony, cookies, samesite

I'm trying to set a cookie in Symfony 4.4 and php 7.2. I don't find any combination for *secure* and *SameSite* that works and doesn't throw a browser error:

> The "last_client_edited" cookie will soon be rejected because its "SameSite" attribute is set to "None" or an invalid value and it does not have the "secure" attribute. To learn more about the "SameSite" attribute, see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite.

There are some posts in SO regarding this issue but none of the solutions fix this, so I don't think this is a duplicate.

I'm developing at a localhost with no *https* so I wonder if this is part of the problem with *secure*.

This is my code (some default parameters will be deprecated in Symfony 5 so I set all of them). *Secure* is the 6th parameter, set to true.

```
$lastClientCookie = new Cookie('last_client_edited', $client->getId(), 0, '/', null, true, true, false, "lax");
if ($lastClientCookie != null)
        $response->headers->setCookie($lastClientCookie);
```

If I set it to null, the cookie is set without the secure flag.

How can I solve this?

Thank you.